# how can i change the size of a table in word using python (pywin32)

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32, autoformatting

### ms word table with python

I am working with **python** on word tables, i am generating tables, but all of them are

auto fit window..

is it possible to change it to auto fit contents?

i had tried something like this:

```
table = location.Tables.Add(location,len(df)+1,len(df.columns)
table.AutoFit(AutoFitBehavior.AutoFitToContents)
```

but it keeps to raise errors

Comment: Could you please post the errors your are receiving?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but try this: "table = location.Tables.Add(location,len(df)+1,len(df.columns),1)". The 1 specifies the auto fit contents of cells. see here: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845710(v=office.15).aspx". The one came from opening the VBA editor in word and typing in the immediate window: "?Word.wdWord9TableBehavior" -- If you type in "?Word.wdWord8TableBehavior" you will get a 0. By default AutoFit contents is disabled.

Comment: I just tested it in VBA, the command you want is "table = location.Tables.Add(location,len(df)+1,len(df.columns),1,1)" -- The second 1 overides AutofitWindow behavior with Autofit Contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change you table creation to use this:

```
//''#Add two ones after your columns
table = location.Tables.Add(location,len(df)+1,len(df.columns),1,1)
```

Information about why you need those variables can be read here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845710(v=office.15).aspx

But basically, the default behavior is to disable Cell Autofitting and Use Table Autofit to Window. The first "1" enables Cell Autofitting. From the link I posted above, the DefaultTableBehavior can either be `wdWord8TableBehavior` (Autofit disabled --default) or `wdWord9TableBehavior` (Autofit enabled). The number comes from opening up Word's VBA editor and typing in the Immediate Window:

```
?Word.wdWord9TableBehavior
```

Next, from the link, we see another option called `AutoFitBehavior`. This is defined as:

> Sets the AutoFit rules for how Word sizes tables. Can be one of the `WdAutoFitBehavior` constants.

So now we have another term to look up. In the VBA editor's Immediate window again type:

```
?Word.wdAutoFitBehavior.
```

After the last dot, the possible options should appear. These will be:

- wdAutoFitContent
- wdAutoFitFixed
- wdAutoFitWindow

`AutoFitContent` looks to be the option we want, so let's finish up that previous line with:

```
?Word.wdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent
```

The result will be a "1".

Now you may ask, why do we have to go through all this trouble finding the numerical representations of the values. From my experience, with using pywin32 with Excel, is that you can't get the Built-in values, from the string, most of the time. But putting in the numerical representation works just the same.

Also, One more reason for why your code may be failing is that the table object may not have a function "Autofit".

I'm using Word 2007, and Table has the function, `AutoFitBehavior`.
 So Change:

```
 table.AutoFit(AutoFitBehaviour.AutoFitToContent)
```

To:

```
table.AutoFitBehavior(1) 
//''Which we know the 1 means wd.wdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent
```

Hope I got it right, and this helps you out.

Comment: IF you don't know how to open Words VBA editor, the default key-stroke is ALT+F11

Comment: btw.. do you know how to make a word table to be in the center of the page? using win32com..

Comment: what library are you guys using?  Im trying to get this with python-docx